# Add-on is not compatible with application version in Firefox ESR

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

My browser addon has the following lines in its `install.rdf`:

```
<em:targetApplication>
  <Description>
    <em:id>...</em:id>
    <em:minVersion>53.0</em:minVersion>
    <em:maxVersion>63.*</em:maxVersion>
  </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

But somehow if I want to load my addon into Firefox 60.3.0esr via `about:debugging` I get the error in the title: `There was an error during installation: Add-on is not compatible with application version. add-on minVersion: 53.0. add-on maxVersion: 63.*.`

What am I doing wrong?